# About a chapter title from Adolf Wölfli's 简历

Tags: translation, culture, history, transliteration, books

In the short 简历 (Lebensbeschreibung) of Adolf Wölfli (I don't know how the name of this artist is officially transliterated in Chinese publications - if you can help with this with a reference, it's a bonus question) is contained a short chapter with the title "Die Sonne bringt es an den Tag". This 简历 was recently, in 2021, republished along with lots of other material, including the complete analysis of Walter Morgenthaler, by the Adolf Wölfli Foundation (cf. [link](https://portal.dnb.de/opac/showFullRecord?currentResultId=%22walter%22%20and%20%22morgenthaler%22%26any&currentPosition=8))

This chapter describes briefly how a hallucination of Wölfli during his time in prison, he attributes to the holy spirit in the incarnation of a woman, reveals himself as a real person a few years later, namely as the woman who witnessed against him in the trial where he was convicted. For further language context, I include pictures of the whole chapter at the end of the post.

My understanding of the quotation is that a mysterious secret or event, in this case the hallucination, reveals itself afterwards, becomes public, "comes into daylight" - to speak more metaphorically - maybe, just like the offences of Wölfli himself, and his health condition, among other things, namely his artistic works, became public and visible for everyone, even years ago, in form of printed publications. Any other interpretation is welcome as well, but it should be reflected in any way in a translation!

That comes to my question: How would you translate this chapter title into Chinese?

DeepL offers me a 成语 as a translation, namely 阳光普照, which I like, but which means quite a different thing. It can be used to describe an optimistic person whose light radiates upon his social environment. I did some research about this 成语 with Bing-AI - so, no further need to explain it.

PS. I doubt that the [book](https://portal.dnb.de/opac/showFullRecord?currentResultId=%22walter%22%20and%20%22morgenthaler%22%26any&currentPosition=8), or even the 简历 contained in it, was ever officially translated into Chinese. Hence, I can't ask for a published translation. If there is still one, it is more than welcome as an answer with reference to the book data.

PPS. Maybe 简历 is not the right word to translate "Lebensbeschreibung". If so, please correct me...

[image: First Page]
[image: Second Page]

Comment: The artist in question seems to be little known in China. Nevertheless there are a few articles introducing him. https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%98%BF%E9%81%93%E5%A4%AB%C2%B7%E6%B8%A5%E5%A4%AB%E5%88%A9/58006382 https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1571783492399639 https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/213783008

Comment: From your description it seems like the situation is 1) Something is initially hidden in the dark; 2) It becomes publicly known after some event. A possible choice is 重见天日, however note that 重 implies there is an initial, explicit action of hiding it, which might not fit the context well.

Comment: Thank you, this answers at least that his official Chinese transliteration is 阿道夫·渥夫利.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, his metaphor is rather neutral about hiding.